# T-SQL Stored Procedure Get No Result

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

Is there a way to suppress all results from a stored procedure result set?

That has both a `EXEC` and a `SELECT` statements.

Edit: Let me explain my problem a little bit more.

The EXEC Statement does a DTSRun that pulls data from ERP and MySQL Servers into temp tables in SQL. Once the data is in the temp tables. There is a `Select` statement that brings back the merged data to the user. The user is an MS Access Database that sends it through to the actual customer on via email. All triggered by a webpage button on the customer side with a "Get Report".

I want to suppress the first EXEC statement result set because I don't want the customer to see the DTS output.

Otherwise, just suppress all then have the MS Access execute the stored procedure then just pull the `SELECT` statement itself.

There are probably 10 better ways to do what I am doing. But I just wanted to know how to suppress the result set of a `EXEC` statement while still running it.

Comment: What would be the point of running it? Do you need values from the output parameters? Please explain the motivation for the question.

Comment: Do you mean by "suppress all results" is to have no results at all or to do you mean to return only the headers but with no data rows?

Comment: The EXEC runs a DTSRun and the select picks off the output from the DTSRun.

Comment: This is important information to include in the question. DTSRun is not a stored procedure.

Comment: Are you using `xp_cmdshell` to run DTSRun.exe?

Comment: Yes, I am. I know xp_cmdshell has a NO_OUTPUT clause, which I already gave a try and didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET FMTONLY ON;
GO
EXEC sp_who;
```

However, it has side effects and weird issues. For example, in SQL Server 2012 at least, if your procedure has a #temp table, you get an invalid object name error. [Erland Sommarskog goes into a lot more detail here](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) (just search the page for `FMTONLY`).

Given your updates (I had no idea you were trying to suppress the output of a DTSRun call), I think a better answer is: add a flag to your stored procedure, and then depending on the flag value, use the `NO_OUTPUT` argument for `xp_cmdshell`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Whatever
  @SuppressDTSOutput BIT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  ...

  IF @SuppressDTSOutput = 1
  BEGIN
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'DTSRun.exe whatever', NO_OUTPUT;
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'DTSRun.exe whatever';
  END

  ...
END
GO
```

Comment: I am on SQL Server 2000. If I set SET FMTONLY ON; the EXEC statement will not execute appropiatedly.

Comment: Then provide more details in the question (and also explain what "not execute appropiatedly" means).

Answer (score 1):

You can issue `SET FMTONLY ON` Statememt

This will suppress resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Commonly there is only two ways to get result from Stored Procedure

1) Select Statement
2) OUTPUT keyword

Most convenient way to suppress result that I normally use is to store the result in a table OR a **column Value to a variable** (example below)

DECLARE @REF_Tool_Property_Name VARCHAR(20)
SELECT **@REF_Tool_Property_Name = Tool_Property_Name**  FROM Tool_Property WHERE Tool_Property_Name = @Member